# MVC:Why my view didn't change when I changed the model and return view(model)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

My model is called Student which has three properties:Id,Name,score. In my view I use model binding,and in my action I search student and return student information, but even I use `ModelState.Clear()` it looks like this code does not work,the view always show the student which id=0.

**Model**:

```
public class Student
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Score{get;set;}
}
```

**View**:

```
@project.bll.Student
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)  
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Score)
 $.ajax({
   url: "@Url.Action("GetStudent","Student")",
   type: "post",
   data: { "id": $("#Id").val() },//id is set to be 0 or 1 or 2
   success: function (result) {
   alert(result);
   }});
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult GetStudent(int id=0)
{
  //ModelState.Clear();
  return View(StudnetRepository.GetStudentById(id));
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your controller to make sure an id is being passed to the `GetStudent` function?

Comment: Yes,I can pass the student id like 0 or 1 or 2 to the controller,but in the view it always show the student id which is 0.

Comment: What does the javascript alert return?

Comment: when you debug, what does the controller receive in the id parameter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Model in your View, you must use the keywork @model at the start

so your View must be

```
@model YourNamespace.Student
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)  
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Score)
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetStudent","Student")",
        type: "post",
        data: { "id": $("#Id").val() },//id is set to be 0 or 1 or 2
        success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }});
</script>
```

than controller must instantiate the model

```
public ActionResult GetStudent(int id=0)
{
  var model = new Student();
  //get the student with repository
  //valorize the studend with model.Id, name etc
  return View(model);
}
```